# Permission denied error with flutter_libserialport 0.3.0: Flutter/Android

Tags: android, flutter, io, serial-port, serial-communication

I am trying to use the [flutter_libserialport](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_libserialport) package for Serial IO communication in Android 12 device. As a start, I tried to run the given example for the package. But when I try to build project, I get the following error-

```
The following SerialPortError was thrown building Builder:
Permission denied, errno = 13
```

I searched for the issue but did not find which permission is missing and what I need to add to resolve this. Please help.

Comment: Seems like this issue ticket: [Android - Permission denied error](https://github.com/jpnurmi/flutter_libserialport/issues/60)